# exercício: repetição

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldade no seguinte exercício:
Faça uma função chamada imprimirAzul4 que mostre 4 vezes a palavra Azul. (necessário utilizar o for)

Consigo realizar o código apenas utilizando o for, mas não consigo transformá-lo em uma função.

A resolução deve ser em javascript

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   console.log("Azul")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Você só precisa colocar o seu código na `função` conforme abaixo:

```
function imprimirAzul4(){
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   console.log("Azul")
}
}
```

Depois é só executar a função com um botão ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Nossa! Obrigada! Pensei que teria que colocar algum parâmetro na função! Obrigada mais uma vez